# Parse Parts of Speech Tagged Tree Corpus with Python without NLTK

Tags: python, regex, parsing, nlp, text-mining

I have tree corpus as below

```
(TOP END_OF_TEXT_UNIT)

(TOP (S (NP (DT The)
            (NNP Fulton)
            (NNP County)
            (NNP Grand)
            (NNP Jury))
        (VP (VBD said)
            (NP (NNP Friday))
            (SBAR (-NONE- 0)
                  (S (NP (DT an)
                         (NN investigation)
                         (PP (IN of)
                             (NP (NP (NNP Atlanta))
                                 (POS 's)
                                 (JJ recent)
                                 (JJ primary)
                                 (NN election))))
                     (VP (VBD produced)
                         (NP (`` ``)
                             (DT no)
                             (NN evidence)
                             ('' '')
                             (SBAR (IN that)
                                   (S (NP (DT any)
                                          (NNS irregularities))
                                      (VP (VBD took)
                                          (NP (NN place)))))))))))
     (. .))
```

I need to parse this tree and convert into a sentence form as below

```
DT The NNP Fulton NNP County NNP Grand NNP Jury VBD said NNP Friday DT
an NN investigation ...
```

Is there any algorithm to parse the above content or we need to use regular expressions to do this and I do not want to use NLTK packages to do this.

Comment: Are you using ntlk.pos_tag(your_token) to get pos tags? please share your snippet

Comment: No, I did not create the pos tag tree. I have downloaded it as a text file from a source. Basically, the text is a brown corpus.

Comment: can you share link of source , so that i can try on it

Comment: I got it from a friend who shared me on google drive. you can copy the text and paste it in the .txt file and work on it. I can't find an option here to attach the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyparsing makes quick work of nested expression parsing.

```
import pyparsing as pp

LPAR, RPAR = map(pp.Suppress, "()")
expr = pp.Forward()
label = pp.Word(pp.alphas.upper()+'-') | "''" | "``" | "."
word = pp.Literal(".") | "''" | "``" | pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars="()")

expr <<= LPAR + label + (word | pp.OneOrMore(expr)) + RPAR

sample = """
(TOP (S (NP (DT The)
            (NNP Fulton)
            (NNP County)
            (NNP Grand)
            (NNP Jury))
        (VP (VBD said)
            (NP (NNP Friday))
            (SBAR (-NONE- 0)
                  (S (NP (DT an)
                         (NN investigation)
                         (PP (IN of)
                             (NP (NP (NNP Atlanta))
                                 (POS 's)
                                 (JJ recent)
                                 (JJ primary)
                                 (NN election))))
                     (VP (VBD produced)
                         (NP (`` ``)
                             (DT no)
                             (NN evidence)
                             ('' '')
                             (SBAR (IN that)
                                   (S (NP (DT any)
                                          (NNS irregularities))
                                      (VP (VBD took)
                                          (NP (NN place)))))))))))
     (. .))
"""

result = pp.OneOrMore(expr).parseString(sample)
print(' '.join(result))
```

Prints:

```
TOP S NP DT The NNP Fulton NNP County NNP Grand NNP Jury VP VBD said NP NNP Friday SBAR -NONE- 0 S NP DT an NN investigation PP IN of NP NP NNP Atlanta POS 's JJ recent JJ primary NN election VP VBD produced NP `` `` DT no NN evidence '' '' SBAR IN that S NP DT any NNS irregularities VP VBD took NP NN place . .
```

Normally, parsers like this will use `pp.Group(expr)` to retain the grouping of the nested elements. But in your case, since you eventually want a flat list anyway, we just leave that out - pyparsing's default behavior is to just return a flat list of the matched strings.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Paul

Comment: I see that pyparsing  is developed by you and I am going through the documentation for more insights :)